# EXCEL VBA - Why does paste with Values yield "#N/A" for UDF - Is my UDF volatile?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a UDF that seems to work fine.  But afterwards, when I cut and paste back as Values, they all come out as "#N/A".  I saw the previous thread where it says that probably means my UDF is volatile, but I don't understand why this should be.

In my spreadsheet

```
A1 = "nustrgsanlab01"
B1 = =LPAR_Env(A1)
```

The purpose of the UDF is to extract the test/prod environment from the name.  The name format should always end with the environment followed by a 2 digit number. So, B1 should yield "Lab".

My UDF:

```
Function LPAR_Env(slpar As String) As String

slpar = UCase(slpar)

If slpar = "" Then
    LPAR_Env = slpar
ElseIf InStr(Len(slpar) - 4, slpar, "DEV") > 0 Then
    LPAR_Env = "Development"
ElseIf InStr(Len(slpar) - 4, slpar, "INT") > 0 Then
    LPAR_Env = "Integration"
ElseIf InStr(Len(slpar) - 3, slpar, "MO") > 0 Then
    LPAR_Env = "Model Office"
ElseIf InStr(Len(slpar) - 4, slpar, "STG") > 0 Then
    LPAR_Env = "Staging"
ElseIf InStr(Len(slpar) - 4, slpar, "LAB") > 0 Then
    LPAR_Env = "Lab"
Else
    LPAR_Env = "Production"
End If

End Function
```

The UDF returns "Lab" as expected into B1.  However, when I copy B1 and Paste back as Values, it changes to "#N/A" (after a few seconds pause).  The same happens on all entries for all environments.

What do I have wrong in my code?

Comment: Cannot reproduce when I Paste Special / Values.

Comment: I suspect you have some other code causing the issue.

Comment: The cases of the comparing strings seem to be different. Have you tried using the 4th argument with the `vbTextCompare` parameter?

Comment: @Rory - so code in a different workbook or in by personal workbook could impact cutting and pasting in this workbook?  The above code is the only UDF used in this workbook, and I only have one very simple sheet in this workbook.

Comment: Does it happen if you open Excel in Safe Mode (hold down the Ctrl key while starting Excel and answer Yes to the prompt)?